# time on UPDATE statements in php script to mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, server, my.cnf

EDITED regex per comment question

I am racking my brain trying to speed up this script on my mysql server. It's running ubuntu and I've followed every article's advice on tuning the my.cnf as it comes to innodb:

```
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 256M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 0
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 6G
```

the hardware on the server is a little old, but it has a terabyte hard drive and 8GB ram. This same code can go through over a million rows in under 2 min on my MacBook Pro.... can the only issue be hardware? On my server setup it takes over an hour. Below is the PHP, I'm just trying to remove any alpha char from 4 cols. Each of those cols IS indexed, but even trying to drop the indexes before each update does not seem to make any change.

```
 $cleanSelect = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, cleanShipment, cleanBOL, cleanInvoice, cleanBatch from MASTER_dups where
  division in (select division from MASTER_import)
  AND (cleanShipment REGEXP '[A-Za-z]'
  OR cleanInvoice REGEXP '[A-Za-z]'
  OR cleanBatch REGEXP '[A-Za-z]'
  OR cleanBOL REGEXP '[A-Za-z]')");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cleanSelect)) {
$id =  $row['id'];
$cleanShipment =  $row['cleanShipment'];
$cleanBOL =  $row['cleanBOL'];
$cleanBatch =  $row['cleanBatch'];
$cleanInvoice =  $row['cleanInvoice'];

$pattern = '/[A-Za-z]/';

$cleanShipment = preg_replace($pattern, '', $row['cleanShipment']);
$cleanBOL = preg_replace($pattern, '', $row['cleanBOL']);
$cleanBatch = preg_replace($pattern, '', $row['cleanBatch']);
$cleanInvoice = preg_replace($pattern, '', $row['cleanInvoice']);

$cleanShipment = !empty($cleanShipment) ? "$cleanShipment" : "";
$cleanBOL = !empty($cleanBOL) ? "$cleanBOL" : "";
$cleanBatch = !empty($cleanBatch) ? "$cleanBatch" : "";
$cleanInvoice = !empty($cleanInvoice) ? "$cleanInvoice" : "";


$updateMasterDups = 
"UPDATE MASTER_dups set cleanShipment = '$cleanShipment', 
cleanBOL = '$cleanBOL',
cleanBatch = '$cleanBatch',
cleanInvoice = '$cleanInvoice'
where id = $id";

 if (!mysqli_query($conn,$updateMasterDups))
   {
   echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn)."<br>".$updateMasterDups."<br>");
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused what the question is.  I also note that the regex you use in your SQL statement is different than the regex you use in PHP (the ^ is outside the brackets in the sql).  You also state you are trying to remove "any alphachars" but the regex beginning with ^ will anchor to the beginning of the line only, and you're only specifying a single character space (the first char).  Can you clarify?

Comment: the regex i had did seem to work but I agree changing it to look for [A-Za-z] is better. This still does not speed up the update statements, however, which is what is killing me.

Comment: The length of the loop will depend on the number of elements you have to iterate over (and will be complicated by factors like running low on memory for large data sets, i.e. swapping in and out of page space).  What are your row counts?  One of the ways you can improve efficiencies for looping over queries is to use prepared statements:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php  so your query does not have to be parsed in each loop over and over again.